# Interactive reporting engine for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, report

I'm looking for a ASP.NET report generation engine, with this feature: interactivity, this means the user must be able to move from more general data to more detailed data (clicking on report elements, like rows or columns).

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a search engine?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want a drill down interactive reporting engine?  SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) in combination with SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) provides the features you need; you can drill down through your data in a very dynamic way, and it works very well.

And you can deploy that to ASP.NET.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Reporing services does provide the functionality you are looking for but there are security issues if you try to put it on an internet facing server.

SSRS was designed to be an intranet reporting tool. This paragraph comes from the first link below:

"Although SQL Server Reporting Services is not expressly designed for extranet or Internet report deployment scenarios, you can successfully put Reporting Services on an Internet-facing Web server to distribute general information to the public at large or private corporate data to authorized and authenticated users."

Have a read of the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159272.aspx
[Internet Facing SSRS Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944762/internet-facing-ssrs-report)
http://blogs.msdn.com/tudortr/archive/2005/11/03/488731.aspx